# Is this the correct database diagram for a sports statistics website

Tags: sql, database

[image]I am making a website designed for local teams/players to add their own league/players to tables and to display statistical analysis. I don't want players to change position or team, nothing too complicated.

`Players` is intended to hold statistical data about a plyer
`Squad` holds information about who plays for which team and what position
`Positions` contains a set list of positions to choose from
`Team` intends to hold all team names
`LeagueTable` should aim to gather teams from `team` and display a list of positions for each team.
`MatchStatistics` hopes to get home and away teams from Team_ID inside Team

Is this a suitable layout? Are there any relationships missing?

Comment: Should be on CodeReview? http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @GibralterTop No, there is no code here to review.